# ps script for downloading xml from url - each output file is unique

Tags: xml, download, ps

I have simple ps script for downloading XML file from url address.

```
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https.url." -OutFile "D:\IMPORT\xxx.xml"
```

I set output file name and directory to save.

script actually working fine, bud I need that each XML will be unique, like **1.xml**, **2.xml**, **3.xml**

I can't find way how can do it.

Comment: i think, better solution is add timestamp on filename. its possible? so result will be timestamp.xml. each file will be own timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Just added to output file

xxx_$(get-date -Format yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss).xml

working fine